# Retrieving right two words in char DB2 field

Tags: sql, db2

Using SQL, how can I retrieve the 2 words from the right end of a CHAR(30) field?

namefield = "My name is Bill Smith"

results = Bill Smith

Comment: What platform / version of DB2 are you running on?

Comment: DB2/400 SQL  v 07.02.0015

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but maybe something like:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(namefield) , 0, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(namefield), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(namefield), 0)+1))) FROM TABLE
```

Replace table with your table. Let me know if it works!

Comment: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - REVERSE in *LIBL type *N not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you use LOCATE_IN_STRING you can say -X to search backwards - as op. to charindex which only only look forward.

```
select
--  locate_in_string(str,' ',-1),
--  substr(str,1,locate_in_string(str,' ',-1)-1),
--  length(str) - locate_in_string(str,' ',-1),
--  locate_in_string(str,' ',-7),
--  locate_in_string(str,' ',(-1* (length(str) - locate_in_string(str,' ',-1))) -2 ),
--  substr(str,1,11) || '<-',
--  substr(str,1,locate_in_string(str,' ',(-1* (length(str) - locate_in_string(str,' ',-1))) -2 )-1),
  substr(str,locate_in_string(str,' ',(-1* (length(str) - locate_in_string(str,' ',-1))) -2 ))
FROM (
  VALUES('My name is Bill Smith')
) AS T(str)
```

Here I start at the point of the last space and search for the prior space and then pass that to substr.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054098.html

> I've included my testing code above -- you can see how I test various parts by removing the comment for that line.  This technique my prove useful in your testing.